# Matriz con sucesion n*m

Tags: java

Eh realizado un programa que permite llenar una matriz de orden M*M(cuadratica) con datos ingresados por el teclado por el usuario de manera visual en Netbeans con java, cumpliendo una sucesión comportamental numerica, la cual avanza diferente en las posiciones índices pares, impares y multiplos 4.

Cuando el índice es par, la sucesión comienza desde la parte inferior, disminuyendo de 9 en 9.

Cuando el índice es par, la sucesion comienza por la parte inferior disminuyendo de 2 en 2.

y cuando el índice es multiplo de 4, la sucesion comienza desde la parte inferior, pero aumentando de 2 en 2.

Compotamiento en casos cudraticos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El programa cumpliendo la sucesión en caso cudratico:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Otro ejemplo con valores cudraticos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como podria hacer que el porgrama tambien realize matrices de orden N*M?

ejemplo de lo que intento realizar
3x5

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Error cuando introduzco valores no cudraticos para la matriz:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi código:

```
public class matriz {

int [][]matrix;
int filas, columnas, impar, par, tmppar, tmpimpar, sp, si, cont;

public matriz(int filas, int columnas) //mi constructor donde recivo parametros para la creación de la misma
{
    this.filas= filas;
    this.columnas= columnas;
    matrix= new int [filas][columnas];
    si= 9;
    sp= 2;

    impar= si*(filas-1);
    par= sp*filas;
    tmpimpar= impar;
    tmppar= par;
    cont=3;

}

public int  [][]llenar() //Aqui lleno la matriz con dicho comportamiento
{

    for(int i=0; i<columnas; i++)
    {
        if(i%2==0) //Cuando el índice es par
        {

            for(int j= filas-1; j>=0; j-- )
            {
                matrix[0][0]=1;
                matrix[i][j]= impar;
                impar-=9;

            }
            impar= tmpimpar;
            impar+=3;
            tmpimpar=impar;

        }
        else //Cuando el índice es impar
        {
            if(cont<(columnas-1)&&cont==i)//Cuando el índice es un multiplo de 4, la sucesión cambia
            {

             for(int j= filas-1; j>=0; j-- )
            {

             matrix[i][j]= par;
             par+=2;
            }
            par= tmppar;
            par+=2;
            tmppar= par;
            cont+=4;
            }
            else //Cuando el índice es impar
            {
            for(int j= filas-1; j>=0; j-- )
            {

             matrix[i][j]= par;
             par-=2;
            }
            par= tmppar;
            par+=2;
            tmppar= par;
            }
        }

    }


    return matrix;
}

public void presentarmatriz(int [][]matrix, int f, int c, JTable nombre)// Creo una tabla de manera visual
{
    DefaultTableModel modelo=(DefaultTableModel)nombre.getModel();

    modelo.setNumRows(f);
    modelo.setColumnCount(c);
    for(int i=0; i<f; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<c; j++)
        {
            nombre.setValueAt(matrix[j][i], i,j);
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: Y estas seguro que tu codigo no lo hace? podes mostrar un ejemplo de la salida con este codigo?

Comment: No, solo sirve para orden cuadratica

Comment: Pone un ejemplo de algo no cuadrado.. a ver donde falla

Comment: Listo, eh editado la pregunta además, eh añadido algunas descripciones con el fin de ser más preciso.

Comment: j e i estan al reves.. .Si vos pusiste asi al principio, new int [filas][columnas];, entonces despues en los for de filas no podes hacer for(int j= filas-1; j>=0; j-- )...matrix[i][j]= impar;, porque ese j que vos manejas por filas, en realidad deberia ir primero.